# boost msm library newbi in firing events

Tags: boost, state-machine

When we call fsm.process_event('eventname');

is there a way to return true if the transition occured and false if "no_transition" was called or an exception occurred?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as no one has answered so far I'll post my quite humble suggestion. You could try calling the current_state() method before and after calling fsm.process_event() and compare the results. This however would not cover the case of self transitions or internal transitions and is not something I would use if there are other alternatives (its a hack at best).

If you are trying to catch the case of an event not being handled by any state and just propagating through you could add one more bottom layer superstate which reports events that reach it (i.e. are ignored by all states they propagated through).

I have had situations where I needed to know if some event actually did something and when it did it (maybe it was deferred first and then executed). In that case I made my MSM post "ACK" messages to an outside queue, I'm not sure if this applies to your problem.

In my humble knowledge interrupts and state machines don't mix very well, I usually either simply swallow them or try and turn them into some event depending on the context. You should never allow you sates (the underlying function objects) to throw.